# rich:dataScroller does not refresh rich:dataTable in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, refresh, richfaces

I have a rich:dataTable and a rich:dataScroller. When I click on the datascroller, my dataTable does not refresh automatically to show the correct page. If, however, I press the refresh button the dataTable shows the correct page.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<rich:dataTable id="applicantsTable"
binding="#{applicantListManBean.applicantsDataTable}"
value="#{applicantListManBean.applicantsList}" var="applicant"
rows="10" width="650">

<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Name" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{applicant.name}" />
</h:column>

<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Email" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{applicant.email}" />
</h:column>

<h:column>

    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Action" />
    </f:facet>

    <h:commandLink action="#{applicantListManBean.showApplicantProducts}"
        rendered="true">
        <h:graphicImage value="/images/icons/view.png" width="15" height="15"
            alt="view" />
        <f:setPropertyActionListener
            target="#{applicantListManBean.tempApplicant}" value="#{applicant}" />
    </h:commandLink>

    <h:commandLink action="#{applicantListManBean.deleteApplicant}"
        rendered="true">
        <h:graphicImage value="/images/icons/delete.png" width="15"
            height="15" alt="view" />
        <f:setPropertyActionListener
            target="#{applicantListManBean.tempApplicant}" value="#{applicant}" />
    </h:commandLink>

</h:column>
</rich:dataTable>

<rich:datascroller id="applicantsScroller" for="applicantsTable"
reRender="sc1" maxPages="7" page="#{applicantListManBean.scrollerPage}" />
```

UPDATE: Javascript error attached:
[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5O7ui.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/5O7ui.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the h:commandLink. It somehow creates problems for the rich:datatable. Use a4j:commandLink or s:link (if you use Jboss Seam) instead.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `reRender="sc1"`. You have copy-pasted this from the RichFaces demo, but you have removed the "sc1" component, so perhaps a javascript error occurs that prevents the table from refreshing.

Also make sure you have your `dataTable` and `datascroller` surrounded by `<h:form>..</h:form>` (both in one form)

Comment: see your firefox javascript console for any js errors and give them here

Comment: I have them surrounded by both <f:view> and <h:form>, in this order.

Comment: try removing parts of the code (some columns, the binding attribute, etc), and see when it will start working (i.e. it will stop giving the js error)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using t:saveState tag or putting  the handler in session scope. The reason this is probably happening is because you have your handler in request scope and since the commandLink is another request, it cannot find the original handler instance to post back to. By simply having this saveState in here, mine started working.

Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Put id for `rich:datatable` and `reRender` in `rich:datascroller` to table as shown below. This works for me:

```
<f:view>
    <a4j:keepAlive beanName="datosCtrlBean" ajaxOnly="true"/>
    <h:form>
        <rich:dataTable reRender="sc2"  width="300" id="carList" rows="10" columnClasses="col"
                            value="#{datosCtrlBean.datos}" var="category" id="myTable" >

                <f:facet name="header">
                    <rich:columnGroup>
                        <h:column>
                            <h:outputText styleClass="headerText" value="Make" />
                        </h:column>
                    </rich:columnGroup>
                </f:facet>
                <h:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{category}" />
                </h:column>
                <f:facet name="footer">
                <rich:datascroller align="left" for="carList" id="sc2"  ajaxSingle="true" reRender="myTable" limitToList="myTable"/>
                </f:facet>
            </rich:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</f:view>
```

Answer (score 0):

is wrong..

try:

```
    <rich:dataTable width="300" id="carList" rows="10" columnClasses="col"
                        value="#{datosCtrlBean.datos}" var="category" >


            <rich:datascroller align="left" for="carList" id="sc2"  ajaxSingle="true" reRender="carList" limitToList="carList"/>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! For visitors who might come by looking for the answer to this question, could you expand on this a bit and explain _why_ one should try this?